# Is there a software to record audio with GUI?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, microphone, audio-recording

While there are many ways to record audio from the microphone over the command line, is there such a software which has a GUI, and has a simple interface?

I am looking for something that has a record button, and allows the user to configure which microphone to record from.

What I have found so far:

1. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/690816/124466) mentions a PPA, which does not support recent versions of Ubuntu
2. VLC can record audio, but it requires one to go through a lot of steps before the recording can be started. I am looking for something that does not have additional features apart from recording audio.
3. `gnome-sound-recorder` does not have an option to choose the microphone.
4. [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/250073/124466) question is about Audacity, but audacity is also a complicated software with many more features. I am searching for a simple audio recorder with a record button, like the Windows voice recorder.

Also, it would be nice to see what GTK and Qt apps are available for doing this.

Comment: @Kulfy It looks like `simplescreenrecorder` allows changing source as well. However, I could not figure out how to only record the audio without recording the screen

Comment: You choose the audio input source in system settings, then `gnome-sound-recorder` will use what you set there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Kwave

Kwave is a open-source sound recorder and editor application for Linux and a nice alternative to Audacity. This application is developed for KDE Frameworks 5 environment (K Desktop Environment). Kwave application was developed by multiple developers and released under GNU GPLv2 License. It’s an nice lightweight and user-friendly application comes with various features.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kwave
```

### QARecord

QARecord is a simple but solid recording tool. It works well with stereo and multichannel recordings, supporting ALSA and JACK interfaces and in both 16 bit and 32 bit mode. By using a large ringbuffer for the captured data, buffer overruns are avoided. It has a Qt based GUI with graphical peak meters.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qarecord
```

---

I hope anyone of these meet your requirements.

Good luck

Comment: [qarecord seems to have disappeared since 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qarecord)

Comment: @JiK Hmm true, but it works on 19.04, 19.10 also. For more info, see “Latest updates” section in this: https://reposcope.com/package/qarecord

Answer (score 3):

Try Audiorecorder

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:audio-recorder/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```